# Laravel session tables always saved one row

Tags: php, laravel, session

I have read and follow the documentation of HTTP Sessions in [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session), I've just curious why session tables is always in one row, when I use `Session::put('key', 'value');`, I can store the data in the session, but when I store another session, the row will not add.

[image]

Even I used `Session::forget('key');` and `Session::flush();`, this row remains.

Comment: Just in case: you are changing the key if you add new sessions right?

Comment: Yes, i do that. But the weird thing is, why laravel had a single row of data even i add or delete more sessions in database?

Comment: And how do you generate more sessions?

Comment: `Session::put('key', 'value');`

Comment: That isn't generating sessions, that is just adding data to the current session :)

Comment: You mean that the data inside of the session table is the whole session data of the application? is it?

Comment: You generate a session when you access the app. However, if you are the only one accessing the app, there is only 1 session. The `Session::put()` method is just a way of pushing data into the session of the current user. Try accessing your app with different users, browsers and PCs. It should generate more sessions then.

Comment: Yeah i know, but how can i delete my session data in database row?

Comment: By logging out or using the red garbage can there in your screenshot. You can also do `Session::flush()`, though I'm not sure that actually removes the session. It at least removes all the data in your session, which is essentially the same.

Comment: I tried it but, nothing happens. it removes only the session data not the session row.

Comment: Good, then the users of your application are traceable ;) Seriously, you [shouldn't delete sessions](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php), only invalidate them. Which laravel does under the hood after some time and else on logout.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your ideas. :) God bless you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `Session::put()` is adding data to the current session, not creating a new one. To create a new session, log in with a new user.

On your question how you can delete the row, you [really shouldn't](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php). Just invalidate them, which Laravel does automagically on logout or after some time of inactivity.